# mvc scaffolding delete raw from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp.net and trying to use mvc scaffolding

I have written a sql Query for a db name ProjectDatabase:

```
    use ProjectDatabase;

    create table USERS 
    (
        USERS_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null ,
        email varchar(max) not null ,
        phone nvarchar(30),
        name nvarchar(30),
        family nvarchar(30),
        password nvarchar(30) not null,
        createdate date not null,
        lastlogindate date not null,
        PRIMARY KEY (USERS_ID)
   );

   create table PROJECT 
   ( 
        Project_ID int IDENTITY(1,1)  not null ,
        Description nvarchar(max),
        usern_ID int    references USERS(USERS_ID) ,
        createDate date, 
        DeadLineDate date , 
        Money date
        PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID)
   );
```

After that I added this database tables to model folder of a mvc4 project

Then I tried to create a controller for the table named USERS, here is the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication4.Models;

namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private ProjectDatebaseEntities db = new ProjectDatebaseEntities();

    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.USERS.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /User/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        USER user = db.USERS.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }




    //
    // GET: /User/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(USER user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.USERS.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(user);
    }

    //
    // GET: /User/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        USER user = db.USERS.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(USER user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    //
    // GET: /User/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        USER user = db.USERS.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    //
    // POST: /User/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        USER user = db.USERS.Find(id);
        db.USERS.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
}
```

But when I open this project by firefox and I try to delete a create raw using the delete button I face with this error: [image: Delete raw error] But when I type the id of the raw in the url It can be deleted easily.

I really can't understand what is the problem with it, I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything

can anyone please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edit and Delete Actions shouldn't have **id** as optional parameter. You need an **id** to know which user to edit or delete, right?

So change

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
```

to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
```

and do the same for Delete as well.

Also make sure that when you are building the urls for edit and delete you are including the id as well.

Something like:

```
@Url.Action("Edit", { id = model.UserID })
```

Mihai